# pandas pivot - summarize two fields, dependent and independently of defined columns

Tags: python, pandas

suppose with a dataframe like:

```
Name    |    Type    |    Year    |    Qty   | Amount
Mike        buy          2019        5          100          
James       return       2019        10         150
Mike        return       2019        15         200
James       buy          2019        20         250
```

I am interested in summing `Amount` by `Type`, and then sum `Qty` irrespective of `type`, like:

```
Name  |  Year  |  buy  |  return  |  Qty
Mike     2019    100         200     20
James    2019    250         150     30
```

How might I achieve this in the quickest way possible?

I've attempted:
`df=pd.pivot_table(df, values=['Amount,'Qty'], index=['Name','Type','Year'], columns=['Type'], aggfunc='sum').reset_index()`

However, this aggregates the `Qty` by `buy` and `return` rather than summing `Qty` irrespective of `Type`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The grouping is different, so `concat` two `groupby`s:

```
pd.concat([df.groupby(['Name', 'Year', 'Type']).Amount.sum().unstack(-1),
           df.groupby(['Name', 'Year',]).Qty.sum()], 
          axis=1)

            buy  return  Qty
Name  Year                  
James 2019  250     150   30
Mike  2019  100     200   20
```